# Interior products, exterior derivatives and one-forms

Tags: differential-geometry

If $\bf{v}$ is a vector and $\alpha$ is a $p$-form, their interior product $(p-1)$-form $i_{\bf{v}}\alpha$ is defined by

$$i_{\bf{v}}\alpha^{0}=\bf{0}$$

$$i_{\bf{v}}\alpha^{1}=\alpha({\bf{v}})$$

$$i_{\bf{v}}\alpha^{p}({\bf{w}}_{2},\dots,{\bf{w}}_{p})=\alpha^{p}({\bf{v}},{\bf{w}}_{2},\dots,{\bf{w}}_{p})$$

---

Now consider the following expressions, where $\bf{d}$ is the exterior derivative and $\nu$ is a $1$=form.

How do you prove that the two expressions are equal to each other?

$$i_{\bf{v}}\textbf{d}(\textbf{d}\nu)+\textbf{d}i_{\bf{v}}(\textbf{d}\nu)$$

$$\textbf{d}(i_{\bf{v}}\textbf{d}\nu)+\textbf{d}(\textbf{d}i_{\bf{v}}\nu)$$

Comment: Are you aware that $d(d\omega)=0$ for any $p$-form $\omega$?

Comment: I know, but it's the order of the operations that bugs me. So, to clarify, in $i_{\bf{v}}\textbf{d}(\textbf{d}\nu)$, $\textbf{d}(\textbf{d}\nu)$ acts on the vector $\textbf{v}$. In $\textbf{d}(\textbf{d}\nu)$, do the exterior derivatives go to $0$ before acting $\textbf{d}(\textbf{d}\nu)$ acting on the vector $\bf{v}$? Also, in the expression $\textbf{d}(\textbf{d}i_{\bf{v}}\nu)$, it's $\nu$ that acts on $\textbf{v}$ and then you have the two exterior derivatives one after the other. So, is this also $0$?

Comment: $i_{\mathbf v}\nu$ is a function $f$ and $d(df)=0$. $d(d\nu)$ is the $0$ 3-form, and contracting it with $\mathbf v$ is still $0$.

Comment: But surely we can't switch the brackets in $\textbf{d}i_{\textbf{v}}(\textbf{d}\nu)$ and $\textbf{d}(i_{\textbf{v}}\textbf{d}\nu)$, can we?

Comment: The first has no meaning other than the second. How do you define $STv$ when $S$ and $T$ are linear maps?

Comment: You should put this as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that because $d(d\omega)=0$ for any $p$-form $\omega$, both $i_{\mathbf v}d(d\nu) = i_{\mathbf v}0$ and $d(di_{\mathbf v}\nu)$ are the $0$ $2$-form. Also note that $di_{\mathbf v}(d\nu)$ has no meaning other than to take $d\big(i_{\mathbf v}(d\nu)\big)$.